# how to define arbitrary plot styles (dash dash dot "--.--." and dot dot dash "..-..-") in mathematica

Tags: plotting

I have a graph with six curves. I have already used all the Mathematica's default plot styles (solid, dashed, dotted, dashed-dotted). So, I need two more plot styles. The natural options would be the dash dash dot "--.--." and dot dot dash "..-..-". I don't want to use symbols (like stars, squares, etc.) as a plot style since the curves represent analytical equations, not numerical simulations. Is there anyway to define these plot styles?

I appreciate any suggestion!

Comment: Read about `Dashing` function as an option to create several dashing types

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but doesn't the Dashing function just change the size of the dash? I'll take a look at it again.

Comment: But also the separation...

Comment: Thanks, it's kinda working! I have to play around a bit to make it as I wanted.

Answer (score 4):

Based on suggestion by José Antonio Díaz Navas, here is a minimal code to this question:

```
l1 = .025;
l2 = .001;
s = l1/2;

Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 2}, PlotStyle -> Dashing[{l1, s, l1, s, l2, s}]]
```

[image]

Comment: `DotDashed` is pre-defined (as `Dashing[{0, Small, Small, Small}]`).

Comment: Is there a way to change the colors of these dashed and dotted graphs while keeping the style intact?